# Catch "Script Error" in error handler of WebBrowser

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a code for navigating to webpage on `UserForm_Initialize`. Sometimes script error's are popping up and I would like to either catch them with error handler or disable somehow.

My current code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim AppXCenter As Long, AppYCenter As Long

    AppXCenter = Application.Left + (Application.Width / 2)
    AppYCenter = Application.Top + (Application.Height / 2)

    With Me
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Top = AppYCenter - (Me.Height / 2)
        .Left = AppXCenter - (Me.Width / 2)
    End With

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        MsgBox "You don't have access to Dynamics 365!"

    Else

        Dynamics365Browser.Controls("Label11").Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("P23").Value

        With Dynamics365Browser.WebBrowser1

            .Navigate "https://crm4.dynamics.com"

            While .Busy
                DoEvents
                LoadingInternet.Show (vbModeless)
            Wend

            While .ReadyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Wend

            Unload LoadingInternet

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

I would like to disable errors like:

[image]

Sometimes this error pops up and this one leads to Excel crush:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `Dynamics365Browser.WebBrowser1.Silent = True` before you navigate to the web page will suppress the script error messages